# Sort a dictionary by average values highest to lowest

Tags: python

I'm creating a game and I'd like to print out the user scores averaged from highest to lowest 
This is my code so far

```
player_scores = {}
for line in reversed(open("playerscores.txt").readlines()):
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' / ')
    score = int(score)
    if name in player_scores and len(player_scores[name]) < 3:
        player_scores[name].append(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        player_scores[name] = list((score,))
```

Names in playerscores.txt are stored like:

```
George / 10
Obama / 10
```

My code takes the last 3 scores from the user(last 3 lives) and uses that as the base. I need print the users names along with the highest average scores to the lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries cannot be sorted. Once you have added the scores to your dictionary, you then need to take them out of the dictionary again to sort them.

Try something like:

```
sorted([(k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in player_scores.items()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

The `[(k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in player_scores.items()]` part is a comprehension that iterates over the dictionary and produces tuples of `(name, average score)`. One we have a list of tuples rather than a dictionary, we can sort them by the score (the second element of the tuple), in descending order.